# Why does my android facebook sdk give a

Tags: android, facebook, oauth

i am trying to publish something on my wall. i am using this code, called by OnClickListener of a Button

```
public void postOnWall(String msg) {
        mFacebook.authorize(this,new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access"}, 
                new DialogListener() {
                        public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        }
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                        }
                        public void onCancel() {
                        }
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) { 
                        }
          }
        );

        Log.d("Tests", "Testing graph API wall post");
         try {
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("message", msg);
                parameters.putString("description", "test test test");
                String response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, 
                        "POST");
                Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
                if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                        response.equals("false")) {
                   Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
                }
         } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

The response string however reads

{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."}}

Also, the Dialog that should be requesting permissions never stays. it starts loading, but then dissapears.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't properly authenticated the user.

I'm not sure if you just left out that part of your code or you're not doing it at all but I would take a look at the [example provided with the API](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/simple).

Comment: well, isnt SSO supposed to do just that? So i should not be authenticating in my app.